# SQL operations to Database catalog

Tags: sql, database, catalog

Are we able to perform SQL operations like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE to Database Catalog (It is more theory question than practice)

Comment: This is not the place for vague theoretically questions my friend.

Comment: Not on most databases.  These are handle through separate operations, such as `create table` and `alter table`.

Comment: You should try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

If a database supports `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and provides instruments for altering the database catalog, then yes, you can use SQL operations normally.

For example, in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html) you can read:

> The system catalogs are the place where a relational database management system stores schema metadata, such as information about tables and columns, and internal bookkeeping information. PostgreSQL's system catalogs are regular tables. You can drop and recreate the tables, add columns, insert and update values, and severely mess up your system that way. Normally, one should not change the system catalogs by hand, there are always SQL commands to do that. (For example, CREATE DATABASE inserts a row into the pg_database catalog — and actually creates the database on disk.)

So, you change the catalog indirectly creating a new database. Nonetheless, with PostgreSQL you can directly change the catalog, using SQL commands like DROP, INSERT, UPDATE and so on.

Some RDBMS don't provide such a possibility, such as Oracle Database, IBM DB2, SQLite or Sybase ASE. Some RDBMS provide `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but it is read-only, so you can't do anything crazy, for example, MySQL. [Its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html) reads:

> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.